# Tensorflow Lite tf.assign() equivalent

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Is there an equivalent operation for the [tf.assign()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) operation in TFlite?

In case it helps: I use this operation to hold the RNN cell states in variables as I process a sequence iteratively at inference time. Another use case for this is storing CNN layer outputs in a fifo queue, similar to [fast-wavenet](https://github.com/tomlepaine/fast-wavenet) implementation.

Comment: One thing you can do is get the RNN cell states as outputs and feed them back on the next iteration.

Comment: That is indeed one way to do that for an RNN cell. IMO not ideal as stacked cells implementation get messy and this approach does not translate well to CNNs. I also need the tf.assign() to hold a fifo queue of CNN layer outputs; I've updated the question to reflect this use case.